# Custom Range in numpy histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

trying to output histogram data using numpy;

```
NUMBER_OF_PRICE_BRACKETS = 8
HISTOGRAM_EDGE_RANGE = (0, 1_000_000)

hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(price_list, bins=NUMBER_OF_PRICE_BRACKETS, range=HISTOGRAM_EDGE_RANGE)
```

I get the following output using above code

```
hist: [0, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
bin_edges: [0.0, 125000.0, 250000.0, 375000.0, 500000.0, 625000.0, 750000.0, 875000.0, 1000000.0]
```

The edges are automatically calculated. Is there any option to force the edges to be created like the example output like below?

```
hist: [0, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
bin_edges: [0.0, 100000.0, 150000.0, 300000.0, 450000.0, 600000.0, 750000.0, 900000.0, 1000000.0]
```

Maybe using range option like

```
range=(0, 1_000_000, 150)
```

Comment: `np.arange(0, 1_000_000, 150_000)` ?

Comment: @user17242583 tried putting ... range=np.arange(0, 1_000_000, 150_000) did not work

Comment: Will you please clarify this question? I don't understand it.

Comment: @canpoint That's because you didn't use the right bounds

Comment: @richardec to be able to view customized bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, since `histogram` will always split your data into equally spaced bins, as if with

```
np.linspace(*HISTOGRAM_EDGE_RANGE, NUMBER_OF_PRICE_BRACKETS + 1)
```

**Option 1:** Supply the uneven bins manually:

```
HISTOGRAM_EDGES = np.array([
    0, 150_000, 300_000, 450_000, 600_000,
    750_000, 900_000, 1_000_000])
hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(price_list, bins=HISTOGRAM_EDGES)
```

**Option 2:** Adjust your range so it does split evenly into the number of bins you want:

```
NUMBER_OF_PRICE_BRACKETS = 8
HISTOGRAM_EDGE_RANGE = (0, 1_050_000)

hist, bin_edges = numpy.histogram(price_list, bins=NUMBER_OF_PRICE_BRACKETS, range=HISTOGRAM_EDGE_RANGE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining only the `bins` parameter to an integer value automatically chooses the value range. However, you can also give a list/numpy array as argument to  `bins`, e.g.,

```py
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(price_list, bins=np.linspace(0, 1000000, 10) )
```

results in

```
bin_edges = [0.,  111111.11111111,  222222.22222222, 333333.33333333,  444444.44444444,  555555.55555556, 666666.66666667,  777777.77777778,  888888.88888889, 1000000. ]
```

Note, that I did not use the `range` parameter there.

Comment: it outputs randomly generated bin range when used with linspace, it worked with using np.array(range(0, 1_000_000, 150_000)), thanks